# lisp: capture stdout and stderr, store it in separate variables

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I have a function which returns a value and prints data to stdout and stderr. I cannot modify this function. I would now like to execute this function, capturing the data printed to stdout and stderr, storing it in two separate variables. If possible, I'd also like to store the function's return value in a third variable.

I've come accross `(with-output-to-string (*standard-output*) ...)` but this won't let me capture both stdout and stderr. What options do I have?

Comment: How about nesting two of those, one for each string?

Comment: That does indeed work, but it seems somewhat inelegant to me. Are there other ways to achieve it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could just use `let` to bind the streams to output string streams. For example:

```
(defun print-stuff (x y)
  (format t "standard output ~a" x)
  (format *error-output* "error output ~a" y)
  (+ x y))

(defun capture (x y)
  (let ((*standard-output* (make-string-output-stream))
        (*error-output* (make-string-output-stream)))
    (values (print-stuff x y)
            (get-output-stream-string *standard-output*)
            (get-output-stream-string *error-output*))))


(capture 43 12)
; => 55
;    "standard output 43"
;    "error output 12"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: And sometimes use \*trace-output\*, like the (time form) function.